# Arrays + useState in React Native

Tags: arrays, react-native, arraylist

I have an array with levels and images.
I need to do as if I have other level, I can use different array with parameters for this level in my array.
But I can't understand how I can do it. Maybe I have an incorrect array.
Please, can you help me with this problem. I just study React Native.

```
const [findObjects, setfindObjects] = useState({
    level_0: [
      { img: require('../obj1.png'), w: 35, h: 50, left: 120, top: 10 },
      { img: require('../obj2.png'), w: 35, h: 50, left: 180, top: 40 },
    ],
    level_1: [
      { img: require('../obj1.png'), w: 35, h: 50, left: 0, top: 0 },
      { img: require('../obj1.png'), w: 35, h: 50, left: 70, top: 170 },
    ],
    level_2: [
      { img: require('../obj1.png'), w: 35, h: 50, left: 510, top: 7 },
      { img: require('../obj2.png'), w: 35, h: 50, left: 170, top: 120 },
  });
```

```
 const hiddenObject2 = (index) => {
    let tempFindObjects = { ...findObjects };
    let tempPostList = [...tempFindObjects.level_0];
    tempPostList.splice(index, 1);

    tempFindObjects.level_0 = tempPostList;
    setfindObjects(tempFindObjects);

    if (tempFindObjects.level_0.length == 0) {
      lvl += 1;
      goToMessageScreen();
    }
  };
```

```
return (

 <View>
   {findObjects.level_0.map((item, index) => {
    return (
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => hiddenObject2(index)} key={Math.random()} style={{ width: "auto" }}>
       <Image
        source={item.img}
        style={[
        gStyle.imgObject,
         {
          width: item.w,
          height: item.h,
          left: item.left,
          top: item.top,
         },
        ]}
       />
      </TouchableOpacity>
     );
   })}
 </View>
)
```

Comment: Not really get what you try to archive. Do you mean loop the `findObjects` dynamically when have more level?

Comment: If I have level 1, I need to use an array with level_1, when I will have a level 2, then call array level_2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem you need to always take the largest level to loop it. you can try this

```js
// you need to make sure the level is in sequence, so you can get the last element of item.
const [findObjects, setfindObjects] = useState({
    level_0: [
      { img: require('../obj1.png'), w: 35, h: 50, left: 120, top: 10 },
      { img: require('../obj2.png'), w: 35, h: 50, left: 180, top: 40 },
    ],
    level_1: [
      { img: require('../obj1.png'), w: 35, h: 50, left: 0, top: 0 },
      { img: require('../obj1.png'), w: 35, h: 50, left: 70, top: 170 },
    ],
    level_2: [
      { img: require('../obj1.png'), w: 35, h: 50, left: 510, top: 7 },
      { img: require('../obj2.png'), w: 35, h: 50, left: 170, top: 120 },
  });

// return object value into array
const arrayData = Object.values(findObjects)

// get the last index of array
const lastIndexItem = arrayData.length - 1

// this will return the last item of array which mean level_2 array in your case.
arrayData[lastIndexItem].map(() => {
 // do your stuff
});
```

Comment: Thank you! You showed me how I need to think